# Typescript module loading error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file module.d.ts with declaration

```
declare module "ArrayItem" {import out = require("models/ArrayItem"); export = out;}
```

Now I have a file Array.ts and the first line is

```
/// <reference path="../module.d.ts" /> 
import array = require("ArrayItem").
```

But this is not working. I got script error.

If I use,

```
/// <reference path="../module.d.ts" /> 
import array = require("models/ArrayItem")
```

Then I did not get any error.

What is the issue in module loading here?

If I have a module.d.ts, then the arrayitem module should be loaded from require("arrayitem").

Correct? Or should I always the correct path for ArrayItem?

I am confused here. Can someone throw help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the owner of ArrayItem.ts then you don't need module.d.ts.  Just reference the module directly.

You are getting a runtime error but not a compiler error because your runtime is trying to load ArrayItem.js for the current path and not from models/ArrayItem.  There is no point in your module.d.ts file since it is only a wrapping of the definitions (but not code) in the typescript module, which your already going to pick up with a direct reference to the module.

So, don't use the ///  and import using require("models/ArrayItem").

Comment: ok..so I should always say import array = require("models/ArrayItem") even though I have module.d.ts file?                                                                  Can you please elaborate what should I do here?

Comment: You have one typescript module referencing another typescript module so there is no need for module.d.ts.  You would only do something like that if you were working with a javascript library in typescript.

Comment: Got it...I have to make some changes. Thanks,